# Similarity between Differential Equation and the Recursion of Number Sequence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In text book, I have learned the solution of a constant ordinary differential equation.

> $x^{(n)}+a_1x^{(n-1)}+...+a_nx=0$
>   First, we consider the character function $f(\lambda)=\lambda^n+...+a_{n-1}\lambda+a_n$. And by considering the roots of this function, we can solve the differential equation.
>
> $a_n+b_1a_{n-1}+..+b_ma_{n-m}=0$
>   This is the recursion of number sequence $\{a_n\}$. When $m=2$, we can consider the character function of it which I have learned. However when $m>2$, can we use the same methods to solve it?

If someone can give an exact answer, I will be very thankful.